# Elasticsearch datetime object in rails not properly hydrated from index, reads as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I have an indexed field defined as `:date` that is a method to determine which `DateTime` object to store.

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mapping do
      ...
      indexes :date,            index: :not_analyzed, type: 'date'
      ...
    end
end
```

And in my `as_indexed_json` I have it listed under `:methods`

```
def as_indexed_json(options = {})
  self.as_json(
    ...
    methods: [:full_text, :tag_list, :category_list, :date, :month, :year],
    ...
  )
end
```

It properly indexes the desired value as `"date": "2016-05-19T09:43:09-04:00"` but when I read the value after searching, the date comes back as class `String` instead of any of the date classes.

I have fiddled with some of the [available `format`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) values on that field such as `date_time_no_millis`, `strict_ date_time_no_millis`, and `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`, but it appears that that only adjusts the setting and understanding of the value, rather than the reading and class hydration of them.

How can I get this `date` value to read back as a Rails `DateTime` as it exists in my DB?

*Previously posted as a [Github Issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/633) with no response.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to convert the string to a datetime value in Rails?

`> "2016-05-19T09:43:09-04:00".to_datetime
=> Thu, 19 May 2016 09:43:09 -0400`

Comment: No, I'm asking why this isn't being done already by elasticsearch-rails

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, You would have to convert the date field from `String` to `DateTime` in your ruby application only.

Elasticsearch stores the [_source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) as JSON and JSON does not have a date datatype so you would have to call a method on the string which converts it back to datetime. You could refer to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) to see how dates are stored in ES.

Comment: All other objects are converted into their proper rails objects. String, Hashes etc... My Rails app knows how to map the values to the index with elasticsearch-rails, it is supposed to know how to map back as well, yet it doesn't